# Canceling Negative Voltage in a Microphone Amplifier Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier

I'm building a microphone amplifier circuit that will receive audible frequency inputs using an ADMP401 Mems Mic to a 741 op amp to a comparator to an FPGA.  The op amp requires negative voltage (+/- 3V to Vcc and Vee, respectively) to work but if I don't cancel it before it gets to the FPGA it will break it, apparently.  Will a rectifier diode do the job? If so, how do you decide which one to use?

Comment: A 741? Are you posting from 1970? :)

Comment: A 741? really? Why havent them been nuked from orbit already?

Comment: A 741 won't operate properly on just 6 volts between the rails.  It really needs +- 5V to work.

Comment: Can you use the built in schematic editor to draw what you are talking about?  It sounds like you are making a digital signal out of the audio, in which case the output voltage of the comparator is the interesting thing, not the output of the 741.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  [Maybe we could get this guy to destroy all the 741s  in existence.](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Doofenshmirtz%27s_schemes_and_inventions/Season_1)

Comment: Awww come on guys, you can't destroy all the 741s.  At least several of them should be preserved for a museum.  To the OP, you say you have an op-amp followed by a comparator.  Shouldn't the comparator be able to provide the ability to output zero volts or some positive voltage?  You're not feeding the raw amplified audio to the FPGA, correct?

Comment: It should, but it's not.  I'm going to try to put a picture of the circuit diagram on here, maybe I'm wiring something up wrong. And no, not feeding the raw amplified audio to the FPGA as I was told that would break it.  Trying to feed it from the comparator to the FPGA.

Comment: After all we still preserve anthrax and smallpox but, one day they may become useful to us. I doubt completely that a 741 ever will.

Comment: So anyway, you might start with a small signal diode (1N4148 for instance) and a pull down resistor before your Austin Powers-style op amp. Then use an op-amp that can run off a single power supply down to 0V like the cutting edge futuristic (1980s) LM358.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+-3V is low for operational amplifier (op-amp), possible that some classical op-amp will not work!
For example, make a search in linear website (http://www.linear.com/products/Operational_Amplifiers_(Op_Amps)). Some of them can be supply between 3V and 6...12V. For example, LTC2050 could fit (redo the search, I have do that very quickly).
You can also download LTspice (http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) and make some simulation to check that your schematics will work.
Then the signal is audio? You can also add serial capacitor after the op-amp to have a protection against accidental DC-voltage (start-up, shutdown, etc...).
Last advice: be careful with high-speed opamp! They can easily oscillate if there is no ground plan or too far decoupling cap.